# Can I get this reopened?

Tags: discussion, reopen

Question related to XCom 2 here:

[What tactics to use for final fight?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256040/what-tactics-to-use-for-final-fight)

The [linked duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255508/xcom2-beating-the-final-mission) is about tactics in general for the whole of the final mission, and the answers there are very generic: use OP abilities, focus fire, etc. Answers like this apply universally. I'm looking specifically for ways to beat the very last encounter, which is a small part (although the most time-consuming) of the final mission. If you haven't played XCom 2, this encounter is an order of magnitude mode difficult than the rest of the game -- especially if you go in blind. Hence strategies and tactics specific to it should be of interest, over and above the generic stuff.

Comment: I voted to reopen. Apparently we're on 2 votes so 3 more people who actually read questions before closing and we're sorted.

Comment: If you want better answers, it's better to post a bounty to that effect rather than trying to ask the same question in a slightly different manner.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Except in this case it's an *entirely different question*.

Comment: @Studoku I disagree (as do the other 4 people who closed the question). Both are talking specifically about the last fight in the last room; despite the title, neither question seems particularly concerned with the lead-up _to_ the Avatars.

Comment: @RavenDreamer The duplicate isn't. It's about doing the other fights in the mission without using consumables.

Comment: @RavenDreamer The duplicate doesn't want to know about final fight tactics at all. It's about managing resources _prior_ to that fight.

Comment: If anything, it's the other question that should be marked as a dupe. Conserving ammo is really just one narrow aspect of the overall problem, which is how to handle the final fight.

Comment: This pretty heavily abuses the idea of what an exact duplicate means, in my opinion. These questions have some significant differences.

Comment: What's amusing is that the duplicate close reason text is: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. **If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.**"

Comment: @Studoku Ah. The title mislead me, then. Your renaming has indeed changed my understanding of the question as asked.

Comment: Yeah, the first question went through 4 different titles. Some confusion makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that these question aren't duplicates, and I have voted to reopen (and as of my posting the question is open). I can see why it got closed - the questions *are* similar - but they are completely different questions.

The first question, [How can I get to the final fight without wasting consumables?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255508/how-can-i-get-to-the-final-fight-without-wasting-consumables), is about which tactics to use prior to the fight in the last room (and with very special restriction of not using consumables).  The second question, [What tactics to use for final fight?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256040/what-tactics-to-use-for-final-fight), is about what to do once you've already reached that final room (and it lacks the no consumable special restriction). These questions are related, yes, but they're asking different things, and the answers to one question aren't required to answer both questions (and the answers in the first question don't address the "duplicate" question at all).

Comment: So this just proves once again that better titles = better understood questions. (The former has had its title altered, and now makes way more sense)